# Convert a one column matrix to n x c matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a (nxc+n+c) by 1 matrix. And I want to deselect the last n+c rows and convert the rest into a nxc matrix. Below is what I've tried, but it returns a matrix with every element the same in one row. I'm not sure why is this. Could someone help me out please?

```
tmp=x[1:n*c,]
Membership <- matrix(tmp, nrow=n, ncol=c)
```

Comment: `dim(tmp) <- c(n, b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a vector `x` of length `n*c + n + c`, when you do the extract, you put a comma in your code.
You should do `tmp=x[1:(n*c)]`. 
Notice the importance of parenthesis, since if you do `tmp=x[1:n*c]`, it will take the range from `1` to `n`, multiply it by `c` - giving a new range and then extract based on this new range.

For example, you want to avoid:

```
(1:100)[1:5*5]
[1]  5 10 15 20 25
```

You can also do without messing up your head with indexing:

```
matrix(head(x, n*c), ncol=c)
```

Comment: It'd also be good to point out that you need `n*c` in parentheses when they're used as the upper limit of a range, otherwise you're multiplying the entire range by `c`. (You have it in the code, but it's worth pointing out.)

Comment: That works great! Thanks all. I just started and not very familiar with the subsetting methods...

Comment: True, I think it's obvious but not necessarily you're right.